# Update value of a reference in recursive method - best practices

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to see how I can update a reference variable in Java methods in a better way. I know that Java references are pass by value - in other words, if I change the value of the reference in a method, it wont retain it in the caller method. But at the same time, I am trying to see how I can deal with these situations better. In most cases we need to return value from a method in recursion, say its base case, just like below where I resort to maintaining a static variable to hold the new head of a linked list that is being reversed. What are the more sensible options that I can use here?.

```
public static LinkedList _head = null;
    public static LinkedList reverseLinkedList(LinkedList head) 
    {
        reverseLinkedListInternal( head );
        return _head;
    }
    
    public static LinkedList reverseLinkedListInternal( LinkedList node )
    {
        if( node.next == null )
        {
            _head = node;
            return node;
        }

        LinkedList tmp = reverseLinkedListInternal( node.next );
        tmp.next = node;
        node.next = null;
    
        return node;
    }
```

Comment: Hey, please note that this is an online coding platform program where they expect the API implementation of reverseLinkedList to be filled by the developer. That is why you see statics there. I am trying to understand what best way this could be done outside it.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need the static variable here. You should be just using the return value, whereas at the moment it's simply being ignored.

This is the kind of solution I would write. Obviously this might not fall into the constraints of your exercise as it is written as if it were a method of a `LinkedList`, which would make a lot more sense in the real world. However the concept is the same, so hopefully it will help you to spot your mistakes.

```
public void reverse() {

    reverseInternal(head);
}

public Node reverseInternal(Node node) {

    if (node.next == null) {

        return node;
    }

    Node reversedTail = reverseInternal(node.next);
    reversedTail.next = node;
    node.next = null;

    return reversedTail;
}
```